# Running a process with nohup after SSH to a server using Python

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, nohup

I am trying to run a program as a background process in a server (AWS EC2 instance).
I have used boto.manage.cmdshell to obtain an ssh connection to the server.
However, I am having trouble running this command:

```
  "nohup daemon-program param 2>&1 > ./logs/out.log &"
```

It runs fine if I manually ssh into the machine and run this command.
My console hangs after ssh-ing into the machine and running this command via python script.
If I remove nohup, the program starts and quits when the ssh session ends.
I would like it to run as a bg process even after I quit.

I tried reading about pty and nohup manual, but I seem to have missed something here.
Kindly point me to a (better?) instruction manual or explain why this fails while manual execution succeeds.
TIA!

Comment: If anyone is stuck, ran the command inside byobu and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is stuck, ran the command inside byobu and it worked.